# Only 3 FPS on Mac mini, boot camp, windows 7

Tags: windows-7, macos, mac, hdmi, boot-camp

Using the GPU test tool from [FurMark](http://www.ozone3d.net/benchmarks/fur/) I get only 3 FPS.

In normal use I notice it when playing fullscreen videos: When the video pans horizontal I get these stripes across the picture.

My setup is like this:

Mac mini 2011 2.3GHz dual-core Intel Core i5
2 GB DDR3 SDRAM (PC3-10600)
500 GB HD
Intel HD 3000
OS: windows 7
Tv: Panasonic G10 50" plasma
Tv and computer are connected with an 2 meter HDMI cable

I've tried to change the HDMI cable - did not change anything.

What can I try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resolve this issue:

Head to the:

1. Control Panel's
2. Performance Information
3. Tools
4. Adjust Visual Effects

Choose: "Adjust for best appearance"

... problem solved

Comment: I always thought that part was mislabeled. There is a "Adjust for best performance and best appearance" and a "make it ugly and slower" setting.